# Is there a way to determine if a site is HSTS-enabled in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, hsts

When a user visits a webpage that is HSTS enabled, the browser detects this and will remember to use HTTPS for requests to that site in the future.  Is there a way to request a page in AS3 and identify whether the page returned was HSTS-enabled (either directly through AS3 in a SWF or using ExternalInterface)?

Comment: When you say " a site ", you mean any site in the web ?

Comment: Yes, but to be more specific, any site that has a properly configured crossdomain.xml file (say, allow from '*').  So can the SWF either request the page itself or a resource from the domain and somehow detect if the site is HSTS enabled?

Comment: There's no way that I know for doing this. AS3 has very limited functionality when talking about HTTP, protocols, response codes and mostly headers. You can check if the site supports HTTPS, but this is no guarantee that HSTS is enabled. Maybe there's some hack to read the headers through ExternalInterface, but I won't count on that. Good luck! :)

Comment: @zretep In reality HSTS is communicated via HTTP response header, so crossdomain.xml has no influence in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like wikipedia define it, [**HSTS** (HTTP Strict Transport Security)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) is an information which

> ... is communicated by the server to the user agent via a HTTP response header field named "Strict-Transport-Security".

Here we can understand that this information is only available from HTTP response headers. For Flash, it's impossible to get HTTP response headers, unlike AIR which is able to get it using a [HTTPStatusEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/HTTPStatusEvent.html) :

> In Flash Player, there is only one type of HTTPStatus event: httpStatus. In the AIR runtime, a FileReference, URLLoader, or URLStream can register to listen for an httpResponseStatus, which includes responseURL and responseHeaders properties. These properties are undefined in a httpStatus event.

For javascript ( or ExternalInterface if you want ), to get HTTP response headers, you have to use AJAX which can only get it with a [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) ([Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)) Enabled server that enable client-side cross-origin requests, otherwise, you will be blocked by the server and your browser wil show you a pretty "*No Access-Control-Allow-Origin ...*" error, of course all that using a [browser which can do XMLHttpRequests across domains](http://caniuse.com/#search=cors).

**Conclusion :** neither Flash nor javascript ( may be in some cases where CORS is enabled ) can really get if HSTS is enabled or not.